# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file error because of sys.stdout

Tags: python

I am recently learning Python. I wrote the following code and I want to continue writing something in console after closing `sys.stdout` with writing in txt, but I get an error.

I need to close `sys.stdout` and continue get information from `print('Hello')` in console, but that doesn't work. Please, i would be glad if you provide code on how to solve this problem.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import sys    

print('getting contests-url')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')
find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'discussionListItem')

for my_href in find_href:
    print(my_href.get_attribute('id'))

sys.stdout.close()
print('Hello')
```

Output:

```
print('Hello')

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: `print` uses `sys.stdout` as the output stream. If you have already closed it, you will need to pass the `file` parameter  (a file or IOstream opened for writing) to `print` in order to keep using it.

Comment: @rdas Is it possible to assign sys.stdout back to the console and not to a file? If yes, how?

Comment: Why not just write to the file and leave `sys.stdout` alone?

Comment: If you close the stream that writes to the console (stdout), it's closed. You can't write to it again. Try to restructure your code so that you don't have to close `sys.stdout`

Comment: Why do you need to close `sys.stdout`? You almost never need to close `sys.stdout`.

Comment: "I need to close sys.stdout and continue get information from print('Hello') in console" I can't understand what this means. `print('Hello')` does not "get information". The point of `print` is to sent information to (by default) `sys.stdout`; of course this does not work if the stream is closed. Instead of reassigning `sys.stdout` to the file, you can specify to use the file as a target when calling `print`.

Comment: (This question is probably a duplicate, but I can't decide what it duplicates exactly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move `sys.stdout` back to the original one:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import sys    

print('getting contests-url')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')
find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'discussionListItem')

for my_href in find_href:
    print(my_href.get_attribute('id'))

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print('Hello')
```

However, to actually redirect stdout in a Pythonic fashion, use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

print('getting contests-url')
with open("out.txt", "w") as out:
    with redirect_stdout(out):
        find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'discussionListItem')

        for my_href in find_href:
            print(my_href.get_attribute('id'))

print('Hello')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about to move sys.stdout back to the original one, but I don't know how. I also try to use contextlib.

Comment: @kgjfdhvd If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark and possibly upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do anything tricky with the streams, open the file in a normal way (using a `with` block so that it will be closed automatically), and simply use `print` to write to the file directly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import sys    

print('getting contests-url')
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'discussionListItem')
    for my_href in find_href:
        print(my_href.get_attribute('id'), file=out)

print('Hello')
```

If you don't actually need any of the special functionality of `print`, and just want to write a string to the file, use its `.write` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import sys    

print('getting contests-url')
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    find_href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'discussionListItem')
    for my_href in find_href:
        out.write(my_href.get_attribute('id'))

print('Hello')
```